# Buttons end up inside eachother

Tags: javascript, html

I have a toolbar with 3 buttons. and one of them has a dropdown.

the html is the following:

```
    <div id="primary-section" class="wrapper wrapper-content">
        <div class="row" id="create-container">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="ibox float-e-margins animated fadeInRight">
                    <div class="ibox-title" style="height: 60px;">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button onclick="javascript:vm.createContainer()" class="btn btn-primary" id="newcontainer" style="margin-right:16px;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Container</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button type="button" id="btn-connect" class="btn btn-success" disabled="disabled">Connect</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group" id="actions" style="margin-right:16px;">
                            <button id="btn-actions" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" disabled="disabled">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a>Start</a></li>
                                <li><a>Stop</a></li>
                                <li><a>Pause</a></li>
                                <li><a>Resume</a></li>
                                <li><a>Delete</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a id="inspect">Inspect</a></li>
                                <li><a id="console">Console</a></li>
                                <li><a>Clone</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ibox-content">
                        <div id="loading-grid">
                            <img src="/public/img/squares.gif" height="130" width="130" title="Loading" alt="Loading"/>

                            <h3>Loading containers...</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div id="grid" class="hidden"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now for some reason the html that results out of this is the following.
The create button ends up inside of the connect button. and i can't for the life of me figure out what the hell is going on. it looks like i closed all tags and quotes.

parsed HTML:

```
<div id="primary-section" class="wrapper wrapper-content">
    <div class="row" id="create-container">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="ibox float-e-margins animated fadeInRight">
                <div class="ibox-title" style="height: 60px;">
                    <div class="btn-group">

                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" id="btn-connect" class="btn btn-success" disabled="disabled"><button onclick="javascript:vm.createContainer()" class="btn btn-primary" id="newcontainer" style="margin-right:16px;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Container</button>Connect</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group" id="actions" style="margin-right:16px;">
                        <button id="btn-actions" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" disabled="disabled">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a>Start</a></li>
                            <li><a>Stop</a></li>
                            <li><a>Pause</a></li>
                            <li><a>Resume</a></li>
                            <li><a>Delete</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a id="inspect">Inspect</a></li>
                            <li><a id="console">Console</a></li>
                            <li><a>Clone</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ibox-content">
                    <div id="loading-grid">
                        <img src="/public/img/squares.gif" height="130" width="130" title="Loading" alt="Loading"/>

                        <h3>Loading containers...</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div id="grid" class="hidden"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so kids, next time you post to SO remember, first check the javascript.

I was prepending the button on the element id of the connect button.

Thanks folks!